# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat Board. at<init>(Board.java:23) at PiratesDriver.main(PiratesDriver.java:14)

Tags: java, jcreator

hi im getting this error msg and i need help

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Board.<init>(Board.java:23)
at PiratesDriver.main(PiratesDriver.java:14)
```

my code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Board {
private final int SIZE=30;
private final int NUM_PLAYERS=2;
**private int diffLevel;**
private Player[] players= new Player[NUM_PLAYERS];
private char[] hurdles=new char[SIZE];

public Board() {
    System.out.println("|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"+"\n||||||||||||||||||||START||||||||||||||||||||\n"+"|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||" );
    System.out.print("Enter Diffculty Level for the Game (0=easy, 1=50/50 i.e. not too easy, not too hard, 2=HARD):");
    **SetDifficulty();**
    System.out.println("");
    players[0].SetName(GetPlayerName(0));
    System.out.println("");
    players[1].SetName(GetPlayerName(1));
    DisplayPlayerDetails();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("<<<--GAME BOARD LEGEND-->>>");
    System.out.println("e = This cell contains an easy enemy pirate.");
    System.out.println("t = This cell contains a treasure island.");
    System.out.println("a = This cell contains an abandoned ship.");
    System.out.println("m = This cell contains a mystery island.");
    System.out.println("j = This cell contains a magic chamber.");
    System.out.println(",P = This cell has a player in it.");
    System.out.println("<<<------- ----- ------->>> ");
    System.out.println("");
    SetHurdles();
    DisplayBoard();
}

**void SetDifficulty(){
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean invalid = true;
    diffLevel= scan.nextInt();
    while (!((diffLevel <=2) && (diffLevel>=0))){
        System.out.println("Error, please enter a valid value");
         diffLevel= scan.nextInt();**


    }

}
public String GetPlayerName(int index){
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Player "+(index+1)+"'s Name: ");
    String playername= scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(playername+" has no Voodoo doll.");
    System.out.println(playername+" does not have a Ship.");
    return playername;
}
public void DisplayPlayerDetails(){
    System.out.println("------------- PLAYER DETAILS -------------");
    for (int i=0;i<players.length;i++){
        System.out.println("-->Player "+(i+1)+"<--");
        System.out.println("Name: "+players[i].GetName());
        System.out.println("Health: "+players[i].GetHealth()+" potions");
        System.out.println("Treasure: "+players[i].GetWealth()+" gold coins");
        System.out.println("Weapon: "+players[i].WeaponName(players[i].GetWeapon()));
        System.out.println("Voodoo Doll: "+players[i].GetVoodoo());
        System.out.println("Ship: "+players[i].GetShip());
        System.out.println("Position: "+(players[i].GetPosition()+1));
        System.out.println("     ------><------");
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

}
public void SetHurdles(){
    Random randNumGenerator = new Random();
    boolean bool=true;
    int rand;
    int e,h,t,a,m,j;
    if (diffLevel==0){
        e=12;
        h=0;
        }
    else if (diffLevel==1){
        e=6;
        h=6;
    }
    else {
        h=12;
        e=0;
    }
    t=6;
    a=6;
    m=3;
    j=3;
    for (int i=0;i<hurdles.length;i++){

        while(bool){
            rand=randNumGenerator.nextInt(6);
            if (rand==0&& e!=0){
                hurdles[i]='e';
                e--;
                bool=false;
            }
            else if (rand==1&& h!=0){
                hurdles[i]='h';
                h--;
                bool=false;
            }
            else if (rand==2&& t!=0){
                hurdles[i]='t';
                t--;
                bool=false;
            }
            else if (rand==3&& a!=0){
                hurdles[i]='a';
                a--;
                bool=false;
            }
            else if (rand==4&& m!=0){
                hurdles[i]='m';
                m--;
                bool=false;
            }
            else if (rand==5&& j!=0){
                hurdles[i]='j';
                j--;
                bool=false;
            }
            bool=true;
        }
    }

    }
    public void DisplayBoard(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("********PIRATES OF 125 GAME BOARD********");
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            if ((players[0].GetPosition()==i)||(players[1].GetPosition()==i))
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]+"P");
             else 
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i=5;i<10;i++){
            if ((players[0].GetPosition()==i)||(players[1].GetPosition()==i))
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]+"P");
             else 
            System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i=10;i<15;i++){
            if ((players[0].GetPosition()==i)||(players[1].GetPosition()==i))
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]+"P");
             else 
            System.out.print((i+1)+":  "+hurdles[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i=15;i<20;i++){
            if ((players[0].GetPosition()==i)||(players[1].GetPosition()==i))
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]+"P");
             else 
            System.out.print((i+1)+":  "+hurdles[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i=20;i<25;i++){
            if ((players[0].GetPosition()==i)||(players[1].GetPosition()==i))
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]+"P");
             else 
            System.out.print((i+1)+":  "+hurdles[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i=25;i<30;i++){
            if ((players[0].GetPosition()==i)||(players[1].GetPosition()==i))
                System.out.print((i+1)+":   "+hurdles[i]+"P");
             else 
            System.out.print((i+1)+":  "+hurdles[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    }
    public void Play(){
        Board game=new Board();
        for (int i=0; i<players.length;i++){
            DisplayPlayerDetails();
            while(players[i].GetPosition()<hurdles.length){

            players[i].Move();
            if (hurdles[players[i].GetPosition()]=='e'){
                EasyPirate e= new EasyPirate();

            }
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

and my main drive is

```
public class PiratesDriver {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
Board piratesOf125 = new Board(); //Instantiate a new board
piratesOf125.Play(); //Play the game 

 }
}
```

ive been trying stuff for more than an hour now, i know that the problem is with my diffLevel being null or something, but i just cant seem to be able to fix it, im guessing that i have to fix it in SetDifficulty() cause that's where diffLevel defined. need help pls.
oh and line 14 is private int diffLevel;

Comment: Can you highlight the line where this exception is thrown?

Comment: where are you instantiating **players[0]** and **players[1]**? It seems that no **player instance** has been added into the array.

Comment: i made the exception lines bold so there is ** around them. players[0] and players[1] are in a different class that i didnt paste since it seemed irrelevant since the exception is not from there

Comment: i also made the SetDifficulty() method bold cause it is where diffLevel is is deffined

Comment: Write players[0]=new Player(); and players[1] = new Player(); on the beginning and then use it. Remember: when you create new instance of array you create it with null (default) values in the cell. You have to  create instances of object before using it.

Comment: wow thanks guys, that fixed it. i fell like that was such a noob mistake

Comment: Great! In that case, please, mark my answer as a helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
players[0] = new Player();
players[1] = new Player();
```

on the beginning and then use it. Remember: when you create new instance of array you create it with null (default) values in the cell. You have to create instances of object before using it.

See also:

- [Creating an array of objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364278/creating-an-array-of-objects-in-java).
- [Arrays of Objects](http://www.oopweb.com/Java/Documents/ThinkCSJav/Volume/chap11.htm)