# Array of record in java

Tags: java

I'm new in Java but have some experience in Delphi and Object pascal.

I want to define a array of a record like as below example:

```
TMyItems = record
   Items: TItems; 
   count: integer;
end;

PlayerItems : array of TMyItems;
```

How can I make it in Java and fetch the items from it?

I just need to define an array for items and its count. how I can do it in Java?

Comment: Don't  try and think about converting Delphi/Pascal to Java. Learn how arrays work in Java and use them.

Comment: I wont to convert I just need define an array for put an object and its count to it

Comment: Every text book on Java covers arrays. Don't learn a new language by asking questions on SO for every single language feature.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, I believe any answer to this would be too lengthy, and would only repeat what can very easily be found in text books, tutorials, or even other [questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5364278/877472). Plus, the answer would ultimately do too much work for you, and rob you of the opportunity to learn this fundamental-java concept concretely yourself. I would search about classes and arrays in java, and go from there (the [official java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) might be a good place to start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, lists are more useful and usually more idiomatic than arrays. Arrays are low-level and a bit clunky.

Java doesn't have records or structs. You'd create a class instead of defining a record.

One of the first things you should check out after learning the language basics is the `java.util` package, which is where you have useful stuff like lists and maps and sets created for you. A good class to start with is [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You can create a list with a generic type parameter that specifies what goes in it.