# Receiving parameter for an array of objects from another class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create one array of objects of my class Percurso for another class Custos, but I don't know how to do this. Here is what is asking in the question:

**Receives as parameter an array of path-type objects**

My code :

**Class Custos** :

```
public class Custos {

    public String calcularViagem(Percurso [] p) {   
        return "";  
    }
}
```

**Class Percurso** :

```
private double kmPercorrida;
private double valorCombustivel;
private double valorPedagio;

public double getKmPercorrida() {
    return kmPercorrida;
}

public void setKmPercorrida(double kmPercorrida) {
    this.kmPercorrida = kmPercorrida;
}

public double getValorCombustivel() {
    return valorCombustivel;
}

public void setValorCombustivel(double valorCombustivel) {
    this.valorCombustivel = valorCombustivel;
}

public double getValorPedagio() {
    return valorPedagio;
}

public void setValorPedagio(double valorPedagio) {
    this.valorPedagio = valorPedagio;
}

public Percurso() {
    this(0,0,0);
}

public Percurso(double kmPercorrida, double valorCombustivel,
        double valorPedagio) {

    this.kmPercorrida = kmPercorrida;
    this.valorCombustivel = valorCombustivel;
    this.valorPedagio = valorPedagio;
}
```

How can I do this ? If someone can help, I will thanks.

PS: Before someone say that this post is similar to other questions about array, it's not,I looked for questions similar that could help and I didn't found any that really could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an array of `Percurso` objects is the same as [creating an array of any object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364278/creating-an-array-of-objects-in-java) To create the array, you will need to include a line like this:

```
Percurso[] percursoArray = new Percurso[LENGTH]; //with your own array name and length
```

However, that just creates an array; it doesn't put anything in it. To put `Percurso` objects in the array (or, more accurately [references to the objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)), you need code like this.

```
percusoArray[0] = new Percurso(5, 2, 1);
percusoArray[1] = new Percurso(1, 1, 1); //etc
```

Or, if the array is long, you could create the objects in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
     percusoArray[i] = new Percurso(1,2,3); //with your own values 
}
```

Of course, a question remains-- where should you put this code? Is the array of `Percurso` an attribute of `Custos`? If so, you might create the array as a class variable of `Custos` and populate it in the constructor for `Custos`. If it's not an attribute of `Custos`, but rather just a parameter for one of `Custos` methods, you'll need this code in whichever part of your code calls `calcularViagem()`, whether that is another method in `Custos`, a method in another class, or from inside your `main` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I will try to do like you said.